# Find in base Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my base, I want put to textBox random text, for example "Nok", click button and, get only NOKIA to my datagridview.

[image]

I try this, but don't work :/

```
var test = from c in stan.magazyn
           where textBox13.Text.Any(w => c.Marka.Contains(w))
           select new {c.ID, c.Marka, c.Model };

dataGridView1.DataSource = test.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, you would use (w=w.Marka.StartsWith(textBox13.Text)).  You would test for the length of texbox.text and if its 1, use this one, otherwise, the other.

Comment: you should edit your original answer and notify the OP about the update. Adding a second answer only when it's a totally different approach to solve the problem. And almost we just need to put everything in just 1 answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this:

```
var lookupText = textbox13.Text;
var test = from c in stan.magazyn
               where (w => w.Marka.Contains(textBox13.Text.))
               select new {c.ID, c.Marka, c.Model };
```

Comment: thanks, this works where (c.Marka.Contains(textBox13.Text)). now I have next questions. in this method, if I put in text box only one char "n", the results is samsuNg, soNy and Nokia... I wany only firs char. maybe something like "n*" and I see "Nokia"

Comment: @SSJ then use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.